# Required claim nbf not present in token (using Firebase Microsoft Signin trying to access MicrosoftGraph)

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, azure-ad-msal

I currently have an app with the following structure: Angular front-end, Node.js server.

We have implemented Google Cloud's Identity Providers to sign in using Google and/or Microsoft.

Google Sign-in and access the Google Cloud Admin SDK working perfectly, however trying to access Microsoft Graph is giving the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Required claim nbf not present in token
```

According to [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth) you can use the access token recieved from the Signin to access Graph:

[Firebase documentation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIMz6.png)

> On successful completion, the OAuth access token associated with the provider can be retrieved from the firebase.auth.UserCredential object returned. Using the OAuth access token, you can call the Microsoft Graph API. For example, to get the basic profile information, the following REST API can be called:

`curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`

When running the above in url I get the same error:

`{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Required claim nbf not present in token","innerError":{"date":"2022-05-26T12:51:11","request-id":"##########","client-request-id":"##########"}}}`

I'm using the **signInWithPopup** in my authentication service (authentication.service.ts):

```
await signInWithPopup(this.auth, provider)
  .then((result) => {
    const credential = OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const accessToken = credential.accessToken;
    const idToken = credential.idToken;

    this.setCurrentUser(result.user);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    const email = error.email;
    const credential = OAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I send the accessToken to my server (app.ts):

```
app.get(
  '/api/microsoft-get-organisation',
  async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    //https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization
    const organisation = await ms.getOrganisation(req.headers, '/organization');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(organisation));
  }
);
```

```
export const getOrganisation = async (headers: any, graphEndpoint: string) => {
  const client = await getAuthenticatedClient(headers);
  return await client.api(graphEndpoint).get();
};

async function getAuthenticatedClient(headers: any) {
  const client = await graph.Client.init({
    authProvider: (done: any) => {
      done(null, headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]);
    },
  });

  return client;
}
```

When verifying the token I can see that there is no nbf claim:

[token screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4ALR.png)

Any advice on what I have done wrong so that I can access Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this error in my environment using vanilla js. To get started with the reproduction I used this quickstart code which is available [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth). Basically, what I suspect is, you are passing incorrect accessToken to graph API. As mentioned in the `auth/microsoft-popup.html`, you need to use the following access token:

```js
var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
provider.addScope('User.Read');
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    // This gives you a Microsoft Access Token. You can use it to access the Microsoft API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken; //This one!!!
    console.log(token)
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);

});
```

then export this token as:

```bash
export ACCESS_TOKEN=FOO_BAR
```

Hit a curl request with this token:

```bash
curl -i -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

To reproduce this error `Required claim nbf not present in token` do the following:

```js
var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
provider.addScope('User.Read');
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    var user = result.user;
    var token = user.stsTokenManager.accessToken;
    console.log(token)
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

- Then take the token and hit the request.